# C# Object name concept explanation

Tags: c#, class, dictionary, .net-core

With a dictionary with a nested class, for example: `Dictionary<int, BankAccount>`,
what's the difference between creating the class first as an object, then linking it to a new Dictionary, and creating the object directly into the Dictionary itself, for example:

- `dict.Add(1, new BankAccount());`
- `var acc = new BankAccount();
  dict.Add(1, acc);`

Is there any benefit of using one over another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advantage of creating the object first, and adding it by reference is, that you hold the reference in the current method, and thus have full access to it.

If you create the object in line with the add method, you would have to fetch the object from the dictionary to gain access.

I do not see any other differences. 
Creating the object first, could have code-maintainability benefits, when you find out later that the object needs to be modified.

Answer (score 0):

The only real difference I could imagine is if you use the first option, the garbage collector doesn't have to hold onto a variable reference and can release the memory sooner. Other than that, it is more concise to choose the first option. Functionally, your options accomplish the same task.

Comment: Garbage Collection cannot clean up the memory as long as the object is in the dictionary.

Comment: Also, it does not matter if you have a object in a variable or not, the garbage collector can still collect it if the variable is no longer used in the method after that point. Because it can do this is why `GC.KeepAlive(object)` exists.